# Access "Where" Query

Tags: sql, ms-access

I am trying to run some Queries in Access and I am unable to find a Query for this,
It is a Hotel Database and Fields Contain Room Type [Single,Double] and Location [London,USA]

Where Room Type is “Single” and Location is London 10% Tax and  USA 20% Tax of Room Charge.

Comment: Your question is unclear. What is the outcome you'd expect? Also, what have you got so far?

Comment: Can you add more informations? Table structures and values for join tables, because we can guess it

Answer (score 0):

You can use an `IIF` expression:

```
SELECT IIF(room_type = 'Single', IIF(location = 'London', 0.1, 0.2), 0) 
FROM   my_table
```

Comment: Burying WHERE clause criteria in Access-specific IIf() doesn't do anyone any good.